# Search-forward typo aborts macros

Tags: emacs, macros

Search-forward seems to not work well inside emacs macros.  For example, say I want to use a macro to help replace `FOO` with `BAR` in the following string:

```
aoeuFOOsnutehaFOOsanotehuFOO
```

I might begin recording a macro, search-forward for `FOO`, and then hit backspace a few times and type `BAR`.  Then I can replay this macro to replace the rest of the occurrences.  Pretty simple.

Suppose I hit the wrong key and search-forward for `FOOO`.  I hit Backspace to remove the extra O, and finish recording the macro.  But when I replay it, nothing happens.  `FOOO` is not in the document, so the macro replay is immediately aborted when the search fails.

This gets annoying in longer macros.  As it is, whenever I record a macro, I have to make sure I type in the search text for my search-forwards perfectly.  If I make even one mistake, I have to cancel recording my macro and start over; otherwise, the macro will just abort when I replay it.

To sum up, if you use search-forward and commit a typo while recording a macro, the macro will not replay properly because it will abort as soon as it replays your typo.

Any workarounds or solutions to this problem?

Comment: The problem isn't that you make a correction with `Backspace`, but that a failing isearch will call `ding` which terminates a macro.

Comment: That's useful, I didn't know about the `ding` function.  I wonder what else calls that function...

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to abort the macro: The easiest thing to do is to simply finish recording the macro (typos and all) and then *edit* it via <kbd>C-x C-k C-e</kbd> (`kmacro-edit-macro-repeat`) to remove the typo(s).

For instance, when you call this command after defining a macro that is supposed to simply search for occurrences of `foo` in the current buffer but contains a typo in the search (you typed `fooo` instead of `foo` before fixing the typo), the buffer for editing it would look like this:

```
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
f           ;; self-insert-command
ooo         ;; self-insert-command * 3
DEL         ;; delete-backward-char
RET         ;; newline
```

To fix the macro, delete one of the `o`s from the third line and remove the fourth line:

```
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
f           ;; self-insert-command
oo          ;; self-insert-command * 2
RET         ;; newline
```

<sub>Note that you don't have to change `self-insert-command * 3` to `self-insert-command * 2`, I just did that to avoid confusion.</sub>

When you're done, hit <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to recompile the macro and close the `*Edit macro*` buffer.

Comment: Nice work-around, but being able to customize isearch to not call ding would really be a useful feature.

Comment: @pmr Thanks for the nudge, I managed to come up with a different solution that does something similar to what you are suggesting...

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of the `ding` function says (emphasis mine):

> `(ding &optional ARG)`
>
> Beep, or flash the screen.
>   Also, *unless an argument is given*, terminate any keyboard macro currently executing.

Digging into the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/plain/lisp/isearch.el) we can see that all `isearch-*` functions that call `ding` do so *without* passing a non-`nil` `ARG`. You could redefine these functions to change the way they call `ding` (not sure if it would be good idea to remove the calls to `ding` entirely), but there is an easier way to achieve what you want:

You can make sure `ding` is always called with a non-`nil` `ARG` by [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) it as follows:

```lisp
(defadvice ding (before be-nice activate compile)
  (ad-set-arg 0 t))
```

As documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Argument-Access-in-Advice.html), the `ad-set-arg` macro

> sets the value of the actual argument at *position* to *value*.

So what the advice does is tell Emacs to set `ARG` to `t` `before` running the body of the original `ding` function, causing `ding` to **be nice** and not terminate keyboard macros anymore.

---

With the advice in place, you can now transform

```
aoeuFOOsnutehaFOOsanotehuFOO
```

into

```
aoeuBARsnutehaBARsanotehuBAR
```

with a "faulty" macro that contains a corrected typo:

```
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
F           ;; self-insert-command
OOO         ;; self-insert-command * 3
DEL         ;; delete-backward-char
RET         ;; newline
3*DEL       ;; delete-backward-char
BAR         ;; self-insert-command * 3
```

---

#### EDIT

As @phils mentions in the comments below, allowing macro execution to continue regardless of errors can lead to unwanted consequences, so *use this solution with care*. If you want to be able to quickly enable or disable the advice so that you can use it selectively (i.e., in situations where you are sure it won't mess things up), define it like this:

```lisp
(defadvice ding (before be-nice) ; advice not activated by default
  (ad-set-arg 0 t))
```

and add a command for turning it on and off to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(defun toggle-ding-advice ()
  (interactive)
  (if (ad-is-active 'ding)
      (ad-disable-advice 'ding 'before 'be-nice)
    (ad-enable-advice 'ding 'before 'be-nice))
  (ad-activate 'ding))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c a") 'toggle-ding-advice)
```

You can then toggle the advice by simply pressing <kbd>C-c a</kbd>.

Comment: It's a neat workaround, but your original answer is the approach I would recommend to jcarpenter (and to anyone else who encounters this Q&A). No matter how annoying it seems in the case of a simple typo, I think that allowing macro execution to continue in this circumstance *in general* is a bad idea, with a lot of potential to produce unwanted changes when the macro executes.

Comment: @phils Thanks for the feedback. I incorporated it into my answer.